# maven antrun plugin in build and profile tags

Tags: java, deployment, maven-3

We are having an issue with deploying our ear to the server. There is a difference between deployment in different environments (dev, int, acc, etc). For every environment we deploy to 1 weblogic server. In some cases, there also needs to be a deployment on a second server.

So for this reason we tried to use an antrun plugin in the build tags like this (since it needs to run on deploy for every environment:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    ... Here is our deployment task ...
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution><id>deploy_default</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And then for environment specific things we use profiles (changing values in a file, deploy to a second server, etc). So here we do again some ant stuff like this:

```
<profile>
        <id>intg</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            ... Change value in files ...
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>0_resource</id>
                            <phase>process-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>run</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

The problem that we are seeing is that if you for example do a mvn clean install -Pintg, it will also execute the antrun plugin in the build. It should not do this because that one is targeted to the deploy phase.

Some research tells us that you can't have two separate antrun plugins in the build tag! Is this the same for one in the build and one in the profile tags? I know we could use the maven replacer plugin so in that case their would not be an antrun plugin in the profile tag, but that is not a solution if other stuff needs to happen with ant in the profile tag.

Extra remark? Maybe it is possible to define the antrun plugin in a default profile, but then is there somehow a way to say that that profile always needs to be executed, even when there are other profiles requested? So like if you would do -Pintg -> then it would do -Pdefault, intg (because else it would be a mess if you need to type default everywhere)

Remark 2: I know you can put activeByDefault to true for a profile but I assume this only executes with the default profile, if you did not specify a -P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config was on plugin level, not execution level. So by putting the configuration inside the execution tags, it will only be executed for the specific phase and goal!

So it should be like this:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <configuration>
                    <tasks>
                        ... Here is our deployment task ...
                    </tasks>
                </configuration>
                <id>deploy_default</id>
                <phase>deploy</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>run</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```